# mongodb querying collection starting with _

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Basically the question is simple:

How can I issue a query on a collection, which starts with _?

For example if I have 2 collections `test` and `_test`, and I am trying `db.test.findOne()` and `db._test.findOne()` in `mongoshell` the first one is working as intended, whereas the second tells me `TypeError: db._testhas no properties (shell):1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place it in quotes and use the getCollection method.  See this [article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection)

Example To create a collection _foo and insert the { a : 1 } document, use the following operation:

```
db.getCollection("_foo").insert( { a : 1 } )
```

To perform a query, use the find() method, in as the following:

```
db.getCollection("_foo").find()
```